# What causes this error , unmarshalling json

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit

I am unit testing a basic controller wherein, in certain scenarios, I return some pre compiled static json from a file.

The problem I am experiencing is that, when I attempt to return this static json inside my response as follows:

```
//records is my json from a file
return ResponseEntity.ok(new JsonApiEnvelope<>(records));
```

I get the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Passed in List contains (at least) one element (type: java.util.LinkedHashMap) that is not JsonApi annotated. Expected ALL contents of the list be of type(s) with the @JsonApiType annotation
    at com.cradlepoint.jsonapiary.envelopes.JsonApiEnvelope.validateTypeJsonAPIAnnotated(JsonApiEnvelope.java:144)
    at com.cradlepoin...
```

What may be causing this behaviour? The json is valid, it has been through a  formatter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad to report that I've solved my issue. Now, the controller that returns the static json simply has a return type of String and produces 'application/json'. That error occurs, in this case, because I was attempting to marshall my static json into a list of objects then send that list, unmarshalled, as json. Crazy, in hindsight